# Set idleTimeoutAction from octopus

Tags: powershell, octopus-deploy, iis-10

I am working on building scripts to set my startMode and idleTimeoutAction from octopus.  My script is changing the startMode correctly, but I keep getting errors with the idleTimeoutAction.  Can someone help me?

Here is the error i'm getting:

> Executing script on 'APPSWDEV01' Setting LeadsAPI property startMode
>   to AlwaysRunning Old value AlwaysRunning New value AlwaysRunning Done
>
> Setting LeadsAPI property idleTimeoutAction to Suspend
>   System.ArgumentException: Property ("idleTimeoutAction") is not found
>   on  \APPSWDEV01\AppPools\LeadsAPI. Parameter name:
>   providerSpecificPickList    at
>   Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Provider.ConfigurationProvider.GetProperty(String
>   path, Collection`1 providerSpecificPickList) There was a problem
>   setting property

```
# Running outside octopus
param(
    [string]$APIName,
    [switch]$whatIf
) 

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop" 

function Get-Param($Name, [switch]$Required, $Default) {
    $result = $null

    if ($OctopusParameters -ne $null) {
        $result = $OctopusParameters[$Name]
    }

    if ($result -eq $null) {
        $variable = Get-Variable $Name -EA SilentlyContinue   
        if ($variable -ne $null) {
            $result = $variable.Value
        }
    }

    if ($result -eq $null -or $result -eq "") {
        if ($Required) {
            throw "Missing parameter value $Name"
        } else {
            $result = $Default
        }
    }

    return $result
}

& {
    param(
        [string]$APIName
    ) 

    if (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($APIName))
    {
        Write-Host "Setting $APIName property startMode to AlwaysRunning"

        try {
             Add-PSSnapin WebAdministration -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
             Import-Module WebAdministration -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

             $oldValue = Get-ItemProperty "IIS:\AppPools\$APIName" -Name "startMode"
             $oldValueString = ""

             if ($oldValue.GetType() -eq [Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationAttribute])
             {
                 $oldValueString = ($oldValue | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Value");
             }
             else 
             {
                 $oldValueString = $oldValue
             }

             Write-Host "Old value $oldValueString"
             Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\AppPools\$APIName" -Name "startMode" -Value "AlwaysRunning"
             Write-Host "New value AlwaysRunning"
             Write-Host "Done"
        } catch {
            Write-Host $_.Exception|format-list -force
            Write-Host "There was a problem setting property"    
        }

        Write-Host "Setting $APIName property idleTimeoutAction to Suspend"

        try {
             Add-PSSnapin WebAdministration -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
             Import-Module WebAdministration -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

             $oldValue = Get-ItemProperty "IIS:\AppPools\$APIName" -Name "idleTimeoutAction" 
             $oldValueString = ""

             if ($oldValue.GetType() -eq [Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationAttribute])
             {
                 $oldValueString = ($oldValue | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Value");
             }
             else 
             {
                 $oldValueString = $oldValue
             }

             Write-Host "Old value $oldValueString"
             Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\AppPools\$APIName" -Name "idleTimeoutAction" -Value "Suspend"
             Write-Host "New value Suspend"
             Write-Host "Done"
        } catch {
            Write-Host $_.Exception|format-list -force
            Write-Host "There was a problem setting property"    
        }
    }

 } `
 (Get-Param 'APIName' -Required)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a look at the file `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config` which contains app pool settings. When an `idleTimeoutAction` is manually configured on an application pool, the result is an entry like:

```
<add name="MyAppPool" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0">
    <processModel idleTimeoutAction="Suspend" />
</add>
```

From PowerShell you can access the `idleTimeoutAction` property via the command:

```
Get-ItemProperty "IIS:\AppPools\MyAppPool" -Name processModel.idleTimeoutAction
```

Likewise, you can set the `idleTimeoutAction` property via:

```
Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\AppPools\MyAppPool" -Name processModel.idleTimeoutAction -Value "Suspend"
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There's a community step template now called [IIS App - Update Property](https://library.octopus.com/step-templates/4eb08b60-142c-4443-92cf-2e069727f438/actiontemplate-iis-app-update-property) that you can use to set the `processModel.idleTimeoutAction` value.

[image: IIS update property step]

And when the step runs it outputs the following:
[image: IIS update property step output]

You can also set the timeout itself by adding another step that targets `processModel.idleTimeout` and set it to a new value like `01:00:00` instead of the default `00:20:00`. Or just set it to `00:00:00` to disable idleTimeout altogether.